# apache mod_proxy, configuring ProxyPass & ProxyPassReverse for cross-domain ajax calls

Tags: javascript, ajax, apache, cross-domain

I'm creating an html5 - JavaScript app (for mobile devices, using PhoneGap). I have to interact with a REST service.

The service is now running on `"http://localhost:8080/backend/mvc/"`

I'm developing my app on an wamp server (apache2) (`http://localhost/stage/`)
I'm using Chrome for browser.

when preforming an ajax call the browser responds: `XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8080/backend/mvc/event. Origin http://localhost is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.`

So I find several ways to circumvent this cross-domain ajax call problem:

1) starting chrome `chrome.exe --disable-web-security`
 => no difference

2) configuring apache using mod_proxy to redirect the traffic.

I enabled in the httpd.conf:

```
proxy_module
proxy_connect_module
proxy_http_module
```

I put a `.htaccess` file in the www root with the following content:

```
# start mod_rewrite
RewriteEngine On

ProxyRequests off
<Proxy>
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
</Proxy>

ProxyPass /EMBackend/ http://localhost:8080/backend/mvc/
ProxyPassReverse /EMBackend/ http://localhost:8080/backend/mvc/
RewriteRule ^/EMBackend/(.*)$ /backend/mvc/$1 [R]
```

I restarted all services (apache,php,..)

resulting in error 500

apache error log: `[Tue Oct 18 14:30:11 2011] [alert] [client 127.0.0.1] C:/wamp/www/.htaccess: ProxyRequests not allowed here`

Any clues on how to resolve this?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I found a working solution:

Enable:

```
LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_http_module modules/mod_proxy_http.so
```

Put this in the main section of your configuration (or desired virtual host, if using Apache virtual hosts):

```
ProxyRequests Off
ProxyPreserveHost On

<Proxy *>
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
</Proxy>

ProxyPass /EMBackend http://localhost:8080/backend/mvc
ProxyPassReverse /EMBackend http://localhost:8080/backend/mvc
<Location /EMBackend>
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Location>
```

So I guess I can't put it in `.htaccess` or I had to set `ProxyPreserveHost On`.  I put `Include conf/extra/` in the `httpd.conf` file and created the `httpd-proxy.conf` file and put the script above in it. Restarted apache and it's working!

Answer (score 2):

You could simply add the given lines in the **httpd.conf** after enabling the proxy modules.

```
ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyPass /EMBackend http://localhost:8080/backend/mvc
ProxyPassReverse /EMBackend http://localhost:8080/backend/mvc
```

Just restart the server and you are done.

Answer (score 2):

In very modern apache, turn on proxy by:

```
a2enmod proxy;
a2enmod proxy_http
```