# How to display data on html from JSON webservice link using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, web-services, html-table

I have given a JSON webservice link, under which we have data and wanted to show it on html table using ajax jWuery. If I download it from IE it works locally by using .json format, but webservice link doesn't work. I have checked whether link is working or not but its working in JSON viewer. What to do?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({  
       type: "GET",
       data : "{}",
       contentType: "application/json",
       //url: 'myfile.json',
       url: 'http://107.22.160.4/ICatService/Service.svc/GetEvent/10/iphone2x',
       dataType: "json",
       success: function(data) {  
         $.each(data.Get_TappyokaResult, function(index, data){
               var tblRow = "<tr>"+
                             "<td>"+data.Back_id+"</td>"+
                             "<td><img src="+data.Back_image+" class=rowimg /></td>\n"+
                             "<td>"+data.Back_type+"</td>\n"+
                             "<td>"+data.DateModified+"</td>"+
                            "</tr>"
               $(tblRow).appendTo(".dataTable");
               $('table tr:odd').addClass('oddrow');
               $('.dataTable tr:even').addClass('evenrow');
        });
     },  
     error: function(data){  
           alert("error");
     }  
  });
});
```

myfile.json LOCAL FILE ---------------------------------

```
{
 "Get_ICatelog_EventResult":[
      {
        "Date":"26\/07\/2012", "Description":"sample event", "Event_Id":5, "Heading":"sample", "Image":"http:\/\/thisisswitch.com\/ICatalogsite\/EventImage\/fc8e84f2-6729-42c0-8e0e-c6961edd2df5.JPG", "Status":0, "Time":"14:00:00", "User_Id":10
      }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Show your web service link. Maybe works with `Ajax`.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a webserver? if no? make sure u do. file:/// has issues with ajax requests. And if you are, you're probably going to an other origin. (`http://107.22.160.4`) So it's a cross origin issue.

The origin of the ajax request need to have the same protocol (http/https) domain (domain.com) and port number (defaults to 80) as the target.

There are workarounds like [CORS](http://enable-cors.org/) (Cross Origin Recource Sharing) providing the [right header](http://enable-cors.org/) information, you will be able to access date on another origin but mostly that requires you to be able to set it on the server side.

Another option is [forwarding traffic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7807600/apache-mod-proxy-configuring-proxypass-proxypassreverse-for-cross-domain-ajax) inside your server.

Or using a php proxy file. That file access the data for you and you can safely access the data or modify headers so you can access them using [CORS](http://enable-cors.org/)

Here is [php example](http://www.daniweb.com/web-development/php/code/216729/php-proxy-solution-for-cross-domain-ajax-scripting)

You can also use flash proxy or any kind of backend language (asp, jsp, ...)

Answer (score 0):

If you have control (or someone you know does) of the web service, you could change the output format to jsonp
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/