# Apply html template to Json coming from webservice without major coding

Tags: c#, jquery, json, asp.net-web-api

I want to pull from a webservice that returns a list of parcels in JSON format.  I want to display the results in a html list that is nice and pretty.  I did some googling, it looks like there maybe some libraries built to do this.

Or do I have to do this?

[How to display data on html from json webservice link using jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11773124/how-to-display-data-on-html-from-json-webservice-link-using-jquery)

Comment: For applying HTML templates to JSON, you can't do much better that knockout.js. I'll dig out something relevant...

Comment: Here's a neat example using JSONP. http://motyar.blogspot.co.uk/2011/12/displaying-json-values-with-javascript.html If you're grabbing the data on the same domain, you might want to load with jQuery ajax instead.

Comment: Are you displaying lots of different data, or if its just a one time thing?  If it's a one time thing then it is probably best to just build the html like that example.  Otherwise investigate different frameworks like Handlebars.js

Comment: @spender is this what you mean? look at the section titled Accessing Web API JSON Data with JQuery. http://www.code-magazine.com/articleprint.aspx?quickid=1206081&printmode=true

Comment: Yes, `$.getJSON` should be fine for loading JSON: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My answer to this in hindsight is angular, or a framework like it. That's exactly what they are good at. applying a view(html) to a model(json). Too bad when I asked this I didn't know it was a thing.

Answer (score 0):

Have a looksie at NewtonSoft.

http://james.newtonking.com/pages/json-net.aspx

Basically, it's relatively easy to convert JSON to dynamic objects and access it like properties on an instance of a class. The process is called serialization and deserialization of JSON. You can roll your own pretty easily too.