# ajax giving blank response

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a xml content stored in the location, `http://localhost:8080/cleo-primer/rest/elements/search?uid=1&query=facebook`

```
<element-list><element><term>facebook</term><name>Bing Facebook</name></element></element-list>
```

I am sending a get request

```
 $.get('http://localhost:8080/cleo-primer/rest/elements/search', { uid: 1, query: request.term }, function(responseData){alert(responseData);});
```

but this gives me a blank response and when I check using my firebug, it shows XML Parsing Error: no element found Location: moz-nullprincipal:{1e7688d3-7b3c-43ae-9142-5b183a7cbfda} Line Number 1, Column 1: inside XML tab

Comment: What does your xml content look like?

Comment: Ive added it above in the qustion

Comment: Does your XML have a doctype? E.g. <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> - and it needs to be presented as XML with the correct headers/content-type http://www.petefreitag.com/item/381.cfm

Comment: What is your content type header?

Comment: @FAngel contenttype header is <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="application/xhtml+xml; charset=utf-8" />

Comment: Hm. Meta is an HTML header attribute. Why it is in XML content?

Comment: [these headers](https://devcentral.f5.com/weblogs/images/devcentral_f5_com/weblogs/dawn/WindowsLiveWriter/AccelerationABCsFisforFirebug_AB24/FirebugHeaders.jpg) are more important (request/response)

Comment: @VDP  Those headers are present response header is application/xml

Comment: so you can rule that out as the problem ;) where are you calling from? http://localhost:8080 or just http://localhost ?

Comment: there's your problem ;) solution provided as answer. Can you modify the headers of the backend? (I guess so cause it's running locally)

Comment: Hm. XML parsing error because of denied cross domain request?... If that does not solve the problem - show us content of Request tab in firebug(should be near XML tab)

Comment: the request header has contents, Accept */*
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Accept-Language en-us,en;q=0.5
Connection keep-alive
Host localhost:8080
Origin http://localhost
Referer http://localhost/testRun
User-Agent Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:14.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/14.0.1

Comment: Oh. Sorry. Not request tab. There should be Response tab. Suppose it will be next to Headers tab. Must show plain response text.

Comment: blank response, he said in the question. So yes it is the source. I can't tell if there aren't any other problems yet but that issue is where he should start..

Comment: I see nothing in response you provided. As the last option I would try to see a response with a [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/). There could be something in your response that breaks firebug completely and does not allow to see response text. Also - does it works in other browsers?

Answer (score 1):

You are doing a cross origin call that is not allowed. You are calling from: `http://localhost` to `http://localhost:8080`. The call isn't executed and there will be NO response. Chrome/Safari will show an error like this in the console:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load `http://targeturl` Origin `http://localhost` is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

More info: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy#Origin_determination_rules

If you can make modifications to the back-end, making it send the right headers, will fix your problem... (`Access-Control-Allow-Origin yourdomain` or `Access-Control-Allow-Origin *` for allow all)

More info: http://enable-cors.org

A couple of other options to be complete...

- If you use apache: You can use an **apache proxy** to forward (map) location on port 8080 to a different port (like the default port 80) I've posted a [question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7807600/apache-mod-proxy-configuring-proxypass-proxypassreverse-for-cross-domain-ajax) about it a while ago...
- You could also resort to **jsonP** (it's not xml but json) using a technique that is loading your resources through a scripttag, you can load json if you're json is adapted to it. (wrapped it a callback function call)
- If you can't do that either your only option is a **proxy script**. A proxy script is a sort of middleware. You make a request to the script the script gets the data, and returns it to you. For example [php proxy](http://jquery-howto.blogspot.de/2009/04/cross-domain-ajax-querying-with-jquery.html). You can make the same thing in asp, jsp, flash or even java applet.

Comment: this  could be the issue.. wil let u knw